# How to set IBOutlet collection's property in batch?

Tags: ios, swift

I created an IBOutlet collection of 4 buttons named `buttonCollection`, I need to set the properties of every button like this:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 1
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

Since `buttonCollection` is an array of UIButtons, I can set the properties one by one, but that'll result in huge amount of code, especially when the buttons gets more, is there a way to set them all at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for button in buttonCollection {
   //do something on button
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use property observers.

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!{
    didSet{
        for button in buttons{
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
}
```